# Error with static pages (error 0x80070542)

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, web-config

I am getting error 0x80070542 whenever I try to access a static file (such as .html). If I try to access a page like Default.aspx, everything works fine with no errors. Is there any reasonable solution to this problem?

I have already seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948217/error-0x80070542-in-website-using-custom-account-in-application-pool), however, I don't want to reinstall whole IIS. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaun/archive/2014/09/02/error-500-0-internal-server-error-authenticaterequest-staticfile-0x80070542.aspx) is describing precisely my problem, however, I already have that IIS_IUSRS in the local policies and It doesn't help.

Thanks for any suggestions.